# No context error in Java, but the context is set immediately after window creation

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I'm trying to make a game using LWJGL 3, but I get this error: `No context is current or a function that is not available in the current context was called.`

This error means that these methods were not called:

```java
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
GL.createCapabilities();
```

However in my code, these are called immediately after window creation:

```java
...
this.window = glfwCreateWindow(this.width, this.height, this.title, 0, 0);
    if(this.window == NULL) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create window");
    }

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(this.window);
        GL.createCapabilities();
      
        ...

        this.world = new World(256, 256, 64); // calls GL11.glGenLists
        this.worldRenderer = new WorldRenderer(this.world);
        this.player = new Player(this.world);
...
```

This throws the previously mentioned exception. How do I fix it?

Comment: Which OpenGL call does cause the exception? Which OpenGL version do you request for your context? Which profile?

Comment: GL11.glGenLists (which is in the World's init function),

Comment: and i don't know if this is what you need but 
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

Comment: Then the second part of the error message is your problem: *or a function that is not available in the current context was called*: `glGenLists` has been deprecated and may not be called in a core profile.

Comment: What do I use instead, then?

Comment: or should I switch to another profile?

Comment: Depends. You can either use a compatibility profile, or you move away from fixed function OpenGL (which is outdated since more than a decade now). Since I don't know in which context you are using display lists, I can't give you a more specific answer.

Comment: I’m only using one context. How do I use a compatibility profile? I don’t really care about using outdated OpenGL, because I will port this to Vulkan later.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`GL11.glGenLists` is deprecated. Switch to using the `GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE` instead.